# CountA using data in the worksheet in order to reference external file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I'm trying to get this bit of code working:

```
Sub GetExternalData()

    Dim wbPath As String, WorkbookName As String
    Dim WorksheetName As String, CellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String, i As Long, N As Long

    For i = 1 To Sheets("x").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        wbPath = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 1).Value
        WorkbookName = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 2).Value
        WorksheetName = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 3).Value
        CellRef = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 4).Value

        Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("'" & wbPath & "[" & WorkbookName & "]" & _
              WorksheetName & "'!" & Range("C:C").Select)

        Sheets("x").Cells(i, 5).Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

Basically, I have a folder path in column 1, file name in column 2 and worksheet name in column three. I want to take these and find the number of items in column C of the reference file.

Currently the equation only outputs a value of 1 when there are 30 some values in the column. Wondering if there is something wrong with how I am calling the `COUNTA` function, result of which is later used in `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. Originally it was just meant to call a specific value in ref file (value at C2), for which it did work.

Comment: You're mixing different concepts: you cannot pass any worksheet function to `ExecuteExcel4Macro` and have it evaluate that formula -  it needs to be a valid XL4 macro function.  See -  https://exceloffthegrid.com/download/4095/   Likely you will need to open each fine in order to run the count.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteExcel4Macro` can be used to read individual cells, but you can't pass *any* function to it: only if it's a valid Excel 4.0 macro function (see https://exceloffthegrid.com/download/4095/)

Easiest to do this by opening the workbooks:

```
Sub GetExternalData()

    Dim wbPath As String, WorkbookName As String
    Dim WorksheetName As String, CellRef As String
    Dim Ret as long, i As Long, N As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("x")
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
            wbPath = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            WorkbookName = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            WorksheetName = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            'CellRef = .Cells(i, 4).Value
            
            With Workbooks.Open(wbPath & "\" & WorkbookName).Worksheets(WorksheetName)
                Ret = Application.CountA(.Columns("C"))
                .Parent.Close False
            End With
            .Cells(i, 5).Value = Ret
    
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this works, just added ActiveWorkbook to close function as I was getting an error otherwise. The only thought is whether there would be an efficient way of doing this on a large number of files, ie 1000, 2000... I can look at python solutions, but VBA+power query has required very little setup.

Comment: I missed that issue on `.Close` - changed your edit to `.Parent` since that ties more directly to the sheet object.  Yes it's not very "efficient"; you could look at using a SQL query to count the values - I don't know if that would be faster but performance is typically pretty good.